Yuga cycle in Hinduism and it's beginning
As per Hindu mythology, there are 4 "Yugas" - Satya/Krita, Treta, Dwapar and Kali which forms a cycle, i.e. after Kali Yuga again Satya Yuga starts.
At the end of the Kali Yuga Vishnu's 10th avatar Kalki destroys all that's unjust and establishes "Dharma" once again, and thus restarting the Yuga cycle which again starts from Satya Yuga.
My question is, how did the very "first" Satya Yuga start and when and by whom (first as in when there was no Kali Yuga)?
